# Join tables from different databases (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, cross-database

Is it possible to join tables from different databases located in the same server, using PostgreSQL? If so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's suppose you are in database `db1` in postgres. Then,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 tb1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db2','SELECT id, code FROM table2') 
AS tb2(id int, code text);) 
USING (code)
```

would join tb1 and tb2 (your other table from different database) on said column. Here in the example I have used `dblink` to do this. `tb1` and `tb2` represent your tables. Replace `table1` and `table2` with your table names and `db2` with your other database name.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dblink` or `foreign_table` through `postgresql_fdw`.

1. dblink

> dblink is a module that supports connections to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database session.

You can read document [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).

2. Foreign Table

> The postgres_fdw module provides the foreign-data wrapper postgres_fdw, which can be used to access data stored in external PostgreSQL servers.
>
> The functionality provided by this module overlaps substantially with the functionality of the older dblink module. But postgres_fdw provides more transparent and standards-compliant syntax for accessing remote tables, and can give better performance in many cases.

You can read document [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).